# Safe global state for signal handling

Tags: linux, concurrency, signals, rust, posix

I am toying around with Rust and various UNIX libraries.  A use-case that I have right now is that I want to react to POSIX signals.  To keep things reasonable I want to create an abstraction over the signal handling so that the rest of my program doesn't have to worry about them as much.

Let's call the abstraction `SignalHandler`:

```
struct SignalHandler {
    pub signals: Arc<Vec<libc::c_int>>,
}
```

I would like this `signals` vector to be filled with all the signals that are received.  My real state is more complicated, but let's use this vector as an example.

I want the API to behave like this:

```
// ← No signals are being captured
let Some(h) = SignalHandler::try_create();
// ← Signals are added to h.signals

// Only one signal handler can be active at a time per process
assert_eq!(None, SignalHandler::try_create());

// ← Signals are added to h.signals
drop(h);
// ← No signals are being captured
```

The problem is that registering a signal handler (e.g. using the `nix` crate) requires a pointer to a C function:

```
use nix::sys::signal;
let action = signal::SigAction::new(handle_signal, signal::SockFlag::empty(), signal::SigSet::empty());
signal::sigaction(signal::SIGINT, &action);
```

I can't pass the `signals` vector to the `handle_signal` function, since it needs to have the C ABI and thus can't be a closure.  I would like to give out a `Weak<_>` pointer to that function somehow.  This probably means using global state.

So the question is: what data structure should I use for global state that can either be "unset" (i.e. no `signals` vector) or atomically "set" to some mutable state that I initialize in `try_create`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of global state, I would recommend using the [lazy_static](http://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/lazy-static.rs/lazy_static/index.html) crate. You can use a macro to define a lazily-evaluated, mutable global reference. You may be able to get a way with a global `Option<T>` variable with that.

That is one problem with this situation though. A big issue you will run into is that it is hard to do what you want only inside of a signal handler. Since a signal handler must be re-entrant, any type of locks are out as well as any memory allocation (unless the memory allocator used is also re-entrant). That means an `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>` type or something similar will not work. You potentially already know and are dealing with that in some way though.

Depending on your needs, I might point you towards the [chan_signal](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/chan_signal) crate, which is an abstraction over signals which uses a thread and the `sigwait` syscall to receive signals.

Hope that helps, another interesting resource to look at would be the [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) function which creates a file descriptor to enqueue signals on. The `nix` crate has a binding to that as well.

Comment: The `chan_signal` crate looks interesting but I'm using coroutines with [`mioco`](https://github.com/dpc/mioco) and I don't want to block on/poll a channel.  However it should be possible to use `signalfd` and add the returned FD to the `mio` epoll set!  That seems like the most elegant solution, thanks for the hint!